# Implementation of the bresenham's line algorithm makes program using gldrawpixels() crash, why?

Tags: c++, opengl, bresenham, gldrawpixels

I am trying to write my own rasterizer using only gldrawpixels() (and glfw). 
I can't use opengl 3 or 4 stuff, because my laptop only has intelgraphics. 
I want to keep my code cross-platform so no windows.h. I can't use pixeltoaster, because it does not build on mingw.
When i run my program it crashes why? I don't know which function causes the error.

Here is my code:

My main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"



GLFWwindow* window;

unsigned int x ,y,size;

float* pixeldata;


// init
bool init()
{
bool init_val;
if(!glfwInit() )
{
    std::cout << "GLFW failed to initialize \n";
        init_val = false;
        glfwTerminate();
        return init_val;
}
init_val = true;
return init_val;
}
//creat window and allocate memory for pixelbuffer
int createwindow(int width, int height, char* window_name, int fullscreen)
{
x = width;
y = height;

size = x*y;
pixeldata = new float[size*3];
std::cout << size;
    if (fullscreen == 1)
        {
            window = glfwCreateWindow( width, height, window_name ,glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(),NULL );
        }

    else
        {
            window = glfwCreateWindow( width, height, window_name ,NULL,NULL );
        }
    if(!window)
        {
            std::cout << "failed to open window! \n";
                glfwTerminate();
                return -1;
        }

    else
        {
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        }
}
//places pixel on screen, doesn't work properly
void setpixel(unsigned int xloc,unsigned int yloc)
{
    unsigned int pixloc;
    pixloc = xloc * yloc;
        if(pixloc > size)
            {
                std::cout << "TOO FAR!";
                glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
                glfwTerminate();

            }
        else
            {
            pixeldata[pixloc*3] = 10;
            }

}


void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawPixels(x, y, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixeldata);
}

int main()
{

init();

createwindow(760, 360,"window", 0);
drawline(10,10, 380,180);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            render();
                glfwPollEvents();
                glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
glfwTerminate();
}
```

My main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_H_INCLUDED

//GL libs
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <GLM/glm.hpp>

// STD libs
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <cmath>

//shared functions

    //main.cpp
    void setpixel(unsigned int xloc, unsigned int yloc);
    //draw.cpp
    void drawline( unsigned int x0, unsigned int y0, unsigned int x1, unsigned int y1 );
```

my draw.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
//does not work, should draw a line
void drawline( unsigned int x0, unsigned int y0, unsigned int x1, unsigned int y1 )
{
int dx = x1 - x0;
int dy = y1 - y0;
int a = dy/dx;
int x2 = x0, y2 = y0;
int b = (a*x2) - y2;
    b *= -1;
    for (int i = x0; x0 <= x1; i++)
        {
            y2 = a*x2 + b;
            setpixel(i,y2);
        }


}
```

I forgot to tell, this is a hobby project.

Comment: What is the error message when the crash happens?

Comment: None, however there is an if statement when the location given to setpixel()* is outside the pixelbuffer "TOO FAR!".

Comment: *the setpixel function is made by me.

Comment: The position of pixel `(x,y)` is *not* `x * y`. And integer division is quite wrong.

Comment: About the integer division they used to be floats not ints ( i wanted to know if it would make a difference but i forgot to change it back). How should i find pixel position?

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem may be in `setpixel()`:

```
void setpixel(unsigned int xloc,unsigned int yloc)
{
    unsigned int pixloc;
    pixloc = xloc * yloc; // <- this is wrong
    if(pixloc > size)
        {
            std::cout << "TOO FAR!";
            glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
            glfwTerminate();

        }
    else
        {
        pixeldata[pixloc*3] = 10; // <- and this is wrong
        }
}
```

The first wrong line needs to be:

```
pixloc = (yloc * bytesPerRow) + (xloc * bytesPerPixel);
```

where `bytesPerRow` is `width * bytesPerPixel` in this case and `bytesPerPixel` is 3

The second wrong line can then just be:

```
pixeldata [ pixloc ] = 10;
```

All that said, you shouldn't write your own line drawing routine. You should just use OpenGL's line drawing capabilities (`GL_LINES`).

Comment: I wanted to know the math behind drawing something on screen. If i wanted to make a game or rendering program i would have used (GL_LINES).

Comment: @user2875871: If you want to know the math behind drawing lines on the screen, you should be aware that line primitives are rasterized differently. Rather than the rectangle-coverage used for triangles and points, lines are aligned to a diamond-shaped grid. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627092(v=vs.85).aspx) explains it in great detail, even though it is related to D3D, OpenGL uses the same basic rules.